# Angular importing child module causing parent module's component get broken

Tags: angular, angular-components, angular-module

I have a `carModule` containing two components `car` and  `car-detail`. I need to use another component named `wheel` from another module called `wheelModule` in the `car-detail` component.

I'm exporting the `wheelComponent` in `wheel.module.ts` and then adding `wheelModule` in the `car.module.ts` file (in the `imports` section of `@NgModule`).

Now I have access to `wheel`'s component HTML tag(`<wheelDetail></wheelDetail>`) in `car-detail.component.html` and it's working fine.

The problem is that now, the main `car` component called `car.component.html` get broken and showing `wheel` component's content instead of `car` component's content!!!

`/vehicle/car/`:

```
car-detail.component.html
car-detail.component.ts
car.component.html
car.component.ts
car.modules.ts
```

`/vehicle/wheel/`:

```
wheel.component.html
wheel.component.ts
wheel.modules.ts
```

Any idea about how to fix it?

`wheel.module.ts`:

```js
@NgModule({
      declarations: [
        wheelComponent
      ],
      imports: [
        ...,
        DxPopupModule,
        ...
      ],
      exports: [
        wheelComponent
      ]
})
```

`car.module.ts`:

```js
@NgModule({
      declarations: [
        carComponent,
        carDetailComponent
      ],
      imports: [
        ...,
        wheelModule,
      ]
})
```

Comment: share the relevant snippets from the component, template and module.

Comment: hi @sofa_maniac, thank you for your answer; I added the ```.module.ts``` files code parts.

Comment: @azarjahrom share template of both modules component html template. and make demo on stackblitz of you problem.

Comment: You are importing the wheelComponent instead of the WheelModule?

Comment: And share the component and template too. or, make a demo on stackblitz

Comment: Seems like a routing issue. You need to provide the routing file

Comment: Wow! you are right @iamentafaz! the problem was because of two auto-generated JHipster routers. in the `wheel.module.ts` there was a `RouterModule.forChild([...wheelRoute, ...wheelPopupRoute])` import and I just changed it to `RouterModule` and now everything working fine. thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad! It helped you to solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

The problem was because of two auto-generated JHipster routers.
in the wheel.module.ts there was a `RouterModule.forChild([...wheelRoute, ...wheelPopupRoute])` import; I just changed it to `RouterModule` and now everything working fine.